# Order terms incorrect in Sympy's 2nd_power_series_ordinary ode solver?

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am attempting to get series solutions to differential equations using Sympy. In particular I am considering

```
eqn = (4.0*N*sqrt(N - 1)*rho(s) + (4*s**2*(N - 1) + (N - 2*s*(N - 1))**2)*Derivative(rho(s), (s, 2)))/(4*s**2*(N - 1) + (N - 2*s*(N - 1))**2)
```

Running `dsolve(eqn, rho(s), n=3, hint="2nd_power_series_ordinary")` yields

```
Eq(rho(s), C2*s + C1 + O(s**3))
```

And running `dsolve(eqn, rho(s), n=4, hint="2nd_power_series_ordinary")` yields

```
Eq(rho(s), C2*(1 - 2.0*s**2*sqrt(N - 1.0)/N) + C1*s + O(s**4))
```

where an extra term of order `s**2` has been added even though the previous solution should be correct to order `s**3`.
More order discrepancies appear at higher values of `n`.

This behaviour happens both in version 1.9 and in the most recent version on GitHub.

I am correct in thinking this is a bug, right?

Also, if I do not give the hint `hint="2nd_power_series_ordinary"` the ode classifier exceeds the maximum recursion depth and thus fails. This happens in versions 1.9 and 1.10, but not 1.8.

Comment: There is a problem with using floating point constants in the sympy symbolic solver. Change `4.0` to `4` and try again.

Comment: I get the same results with or without floats in all mentioned versions including 1.8. In any case this looks like a bug and should be reported as an issue on GitHub rather than here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues